# deshabilitar y habilitar "botones" de la etiqueta "a"

Tags: jquery

El inconveniente que tengo que de inicio debo de des-habilitar los botones de arriba y abajo, y que no realiza ninguna función, hasta que se de click en el botón de inicio y habilite los botones y realize las funciones que ya tiene, el problema es que no debo de cambiar las etiquetas (a) por unas etiquetas (button) y como ya le di unas funciones de click a cada botón no me deja realizar ya que buscando vi que para des-habilitarlas es con `.bind()` pero igualmente realiza la función que ya le había dado en el código.

No se tiene que cambiar de etiqueta a (button).

**HTML**

```
<a class='btn-up'><span class='triangle-up'></span></a>
<a class='btn-down'><span class='triangle-down'></span></a>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(".btn-up").bind("click",false);
$(".btn-down").bind("click",false);

$("#btniniciar").on("click", function(){
    $("#btniniciar").hide();
    $("#btnreiniciar").show();
    $("#masaInputID").prop("disabled",false);
    $("#masaInputID").css("color","white");
    casos(masa);
    updateM(masa);
});
/*BOTON ABAJO*/
var decreaseMasa = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-down')[0];
    decreaseMasa.onclick = function() {
        masa = Math.round(masaInput.value);
        masa = masa - 100;
        if(masa <= 100){
            masa = 100;
        }
        casos(masa);
        updateM(masa);
    };
/*BOTON ARRIBA*/
var increaseMasa = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-up')[0];
    increaseMasa.onclick = function() {
        masa = Math.round(masaInput.value);
        masa = masa + 100;
        if(masa >= 500){
            masa = 500;
        }
        casos(masa);
        updateM(masa);
    };
```

Comment: Deberias agregar el codigo completo.  Te faltan los botones de iniciar y reiniciar, y tambien las variables que tienes en tucodigo que no estan definidas como masaInput.

Comment: los creas con un atributo disabled y al iniciar les quitas el atributo, algo como esto : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34267489/1423096

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con jQuery puedes realizarlo sin la necesidad de cambiar las etiquetas o sus atributos:

```
// Una varible que por defecto esta en false
var activos = false;

$("a").click(function (e) {
    // Si los la variable es false, evita que `a` se ejecute normalmente
    if(!activos){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Cuando necesites activar los botones, simplemente estableces la variable a `true` y los botones funcionaran normalmente

```
activos = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

algo como esto

```html
function btn1(){
        alert("btn1");
 $("#b2").removeClass("disabled");
 $("#b1").addClass("disabled");
}
function btn2(){
 alert("btn2");
 $("#b1").removeClass("disabled");
 $("#b2").addClass("disabled");
}
```